# How to load data in dataGrid direct from raw Json data from url in C#?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, datagrid

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Height="150" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="60" Width="402">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Product ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding productId}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Product Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding productName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding unitPrice}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Units in stock" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding unitsInStock}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Reorder Level" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding reorderLevel}"/>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="215" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="178" Width="402"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="productId" Binding="{Binding Path=productId}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="productName" Binding="{Binding Path=productName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="unitPrice" Binding="{Binding Path=unitPrice}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="unitsInStock" Binding="{Binding Path=unitsInStock}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="reorderLevel" Binding="{Binding Path=reorderLevel}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Above are two WPF controls, listBox and dataGrid. I am able to directly load into listBox from raw Json data from a URL. I want to do same for dataGrid. I want to load data into dataGrid from raw Json data. Please help.

Product class contains 5 attributes.

Backend ::

```
private void TestConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://192.168.167.1:8080/StudentOnlineRetailerWeb/rest/product";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string reply = client.DownloadString(url);
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
        listView.Items.Clear();
        List<Product> product;

        product = (List<Product>)serializer.ReadObject(client.OpenRead(url));
        foreach (Product temp in product)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(temp);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy way use jsonorm from nuget and create a data layer from received json by (http://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not load from a Datatable, that would be easy

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```